# Change start date so that all other dates follow suit MS Project

Tags: ms-project

I have a project completed in MS Project but I made an error on the start date. How do I change the start date to another date so that all other dates automatically change? I tried just changing the start date but the other dates will not change?

Answer (score 0):

Have you specified Predecessor links between the individual Tasks? If so, you can simply change the Start of the first Task and all the others will move. If not add Predecessor links between the tasks - even if they're just to set them all to the same Start (e.g. if you want the Task in Row 4 to start at the same time as the one in Row 3, enter 3SS in Predecessors for Row 4). Then change the Start of the first Task; the rest will move and the Project Start will also be automatically updated.

Answer (score 0):

If your tasks are all "automatically scheduled" then moving one task to a later date should automatically move the others. If your tasks are "manually scheduled" then they won't automatically adjust. Switch all tasks to "automatically scheduled" and it should fix it! ^-^

All the best!

Matthew